# What does xfce4 power-manager do in "presentation mode"?

Tags: linux, xorg, xfce

What exactly does the xfce4-power-manager if I press the button for presentation mode?

Is it called X function? Or what else?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It does two things, both intended to keep automatic features from messing up a presentation where you don't touch the machine for a long time (e.g. a teacher showing a video to a class):

- Turns off DPMS (Display Power Management Signaling) so your screen won't blank or sleep
- Prevents screensaver mode from activating

Answer (score 16):

It prevents your system from suspending or hibernating.